# Kivy - cannot change button state from function outside kv language

Tags: python, widget, kivy, state, togglebutton

I am trying to change the state of a ToggleButton from a function.

The only way I've been able to get the state change to work is if the function that changes the state is within the root widget AND I call that function from kv language.

Here is some simplified code I set up to test the problem:

python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MainPanel(BoxLayout):
    def togOn(self):
        self.ids.node1_power.state = 'down'

class avcsServerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global root
        root = self.root
        return Builder.load_file('avcsserver.kv')

    def press(self):
        root.togOn()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    avcsServerApp().run()
```

kv code:

```
<Button>:
    font_size: 20
    color: .12,.13,.14,1
    border: 25, 25, 25, 25
    background_down: 'buttono.png'
    background_normal: 'button.png'

MainPanel:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .12,.13,.14,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    ToggleButton:
        id: node1_power
        text: "POWER"
    Button:
        text: "TOGGLE"
        on_release: app.press()
```

When calling the `togOn()` function straight from the kv code (i.e. `on_release: root.togOn()`), it works as expected, but calling it through `press()` fails to update the button state.

Alternatively, putting something like `root.ids.node1_power.state = 'down'` directly in the `press()` function does not work either.

I suspect the method I'm using to reference the root widget through my Python code is to blame, as it doesn't seem proper (the `global root` and `root=self.root` lines), but I'm new to Kivy and Python, and it was the only way I have found to do so.

Comment: Yep, the whole `gloabl root` thing is silly and breaks things. Just directly using `self.root` solved my problems. I don't know why somebody recommended that method...

Answer (score 0):

The whole `global root` is really a bad idea. You were very close. The following python code should work as you intend it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MainPanel(BoxLayout):
    # Not need for the togOn method
    pass

class avcsServerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('avcsserver.kv')

    def press(self):
        # The root attribute is readily available inside the app 
        # class instance. 
        self.root.ids.node1_power.state = "down" if \
            self.root.ids.node1_power.state != "down" else "normal"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    avcsServerApp().run()
```